# How to run command when a specific network interface has low outgoing bandwidth for a specific time period?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, nic, upload, bandwidth

How to run command when a specific network interface has low outgoing bandwidth for a specific time period?

```
enp7s0 [192.168.0.101] (1/4):
=============================
Incoming:                                                         Outgoing:
Curr: 19.49 MBit/s                                                Curr: 868.70 MBit/s
```

From the above, If the value of Outgoing of enp7s0 becomes lower than 10 mbps for a period of 5 minutes then run specific command, how do I do this?

Comment: Rather than "detect then fix", you should "diagnose then really fix"

Comment: Use the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b 0 /dev/enp7s0` to see log entries.